# Pretty Print multiple occurrences of JSON data in a file to an output file

Tags: json

I am trying pretty print a JOSN data file with multiple occurrences of the following data below using the pprint function.

**Content of data file**

> {"_abcd": {"options": {}, "module": "xxxx", "crawler": "1234567890"}, "hash": 1048951621, "os": null, "ip": sgdgdfd, "isp": "ASGSFDF", "port": YYY, "hostnames": [], "location": {"city": "rtyf", "region_code": "00", "area_code": null, "longitude": 111.23344, "country_code3": "xyz", "country_name": "qazwsx", "postal_code": null, "dma_code": null, "country_code": "yy", "latitude": 1.11111}, "timestamp": "XXXXX", "domains": [], "org": "FFFFF", "data": "Unit ID: 0\n-- Slave ID Data: \t()\n\nUnit ID: 255\n-- Slave ID Data: \t()\n\n", "asn": "44444", "transport": "tcp", "ip_str": "1.2.3.4"}
>   {"_abcd": {"options": {}, "module": "yyyy", "crawler": "999999"}, "hash": 35473835, "os": null, "ip": sgdgdfd, "isp": "TYUUF", "port": YYY, "hostnames": [], "location": {"city": "wewd", "region_code": "00", "area_code": null, "longitude": 222.3456, "country_code3": "xyz", "country_name": "qazwsx", "postal_code": null, "dma_code": null, "country_code": "yy", "latitude": 1.11111}, "timestamp": "XXXXX", "domains": [], "org": "DDDD", "data": "Unit ID: 0\n-- Slave ID Data: \t()\n\nUnit ID: 255\n-- Slave ID Data: \t()\n\n", "asn": "44444", "transport": "tcp", "ip_str": "4.3.2.1"}
>   ...more of the same data as above

I found the code in this forum and modified it to write the output to a file:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
data = json.load(data_file)

with open('outfile.json,'w') as data_out

pprint(data,stream=data_out)
```

It works fine if the date file contains just 1 occurrence of the data and will fail when it has multiple occurrences.

How to modify the code to make it work with multiple occurrences of my data?

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it.  There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scan past it to find the button) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 1):

> It works fine if the date file contains just 1 occurrence of the data and will fail when it has multiple occurrences.

If you mean you have

```
{"_abcd": ...}
{"_abcd": ...}
{"_abcd": ...}
```

That's invalid JSON. To make it valid, you wrap those objects in an array with `[` at the beginning, commas in-between, and `]` at the end:

```
[
{"_abcd": ...},
{"_abcd": ...},
{"_abcd": ...}
]
```